# Hibernate: @Formula query field using another @Formula field

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want field `idEmpresa` to be a @Formula field using `idDepartamento` (that is another @Formula field) in `WHERE` statement.

```
@Entity
public class CfgUsuario {

    //More fields
    private String idDepartamento;
    private String idEmpresa;


    @Formula("(SELECT ud.IdDepartamento FROM UsuarioDpto ud WHERE ud.PorDefecto = 'S' AND ud.IdUsuario = idUsuario)")
    public String getIdDepartamento() {
        return idDepartamento;
    }

    public void setIdDepartamento(String idDepartamento) {
        this.idDepartamento = idDepartamento;
    }

    @Formula("(SELECT d.IdEmpresa FROM Departamento d WHERE d.IdDepartamento = idDepartamento)")
    public String getIdEmpresa() {
        return idEmpresa;
    }

    public void setIdEmpresa(String idEmpresa) {
        this.idEmpresa = idEmpresa;
    }

}
```

But I get:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Column name 'idDepartamento' invalid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to create a valid *HQL* / *JPQL* statement, but if you read the JavaDoc of `Formula` you will see:

> The formula has to be a valid *SQL* fragment

So you can't reference *any* field from your class, only tables and columns from your database.

But you can change your `Formula` to use a `JOIN` instead:

```
@Formula("(SELECT ud.IdDepartamento FROM UsuarioDpto ud WHERE ud.PorDefecto = 'S' AND ud.IdUsuario = idUsuario)")
public String getIdDepartamento() {
    return idDepartamento;
}

@Formula("(SELECT d.IdEmpresa FROM Departamento d JOIN UsuarioDpto ud ON d.IdDepartamento = uid.idDepartamento WHERE ud.PorDefecto = 'S' AND ud.IdUsuario = idUsuario)")
public String getIdEmpresa() {
    return idEmpresa;
}
```

And I would remove the *setters* of your formulas, as they will confuse any user of your API. Formula fields are usually read-only.