# How do i use reserved table column in hibernate @Formula

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm trying to use column name that is a reserved keyword in hibernate.
Even with quotes i'm still getting errors.

I need to create a subquery using @Formula.

Table looks like this below, notice the column named "row", we are querying this from an external system and this cannot be changed. This is the source of the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTestTable (
    id int,
    `row` int NOT NULL,
    column1 int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    column2 int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, `row`)
);
```

Entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyTestTable implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "[row]")
    private int row;

    @Formula("select o.column1 + o.column2" +
            " from MyTestTable o where o.row = `row` AND o.id = id")
    private int calculatedSum;

    ... getters and setters
}
```

(calculatedSum uses 20+ columns in the real world)

When trying to get the value of calculatedSum i get the error:

Syntax error in SQL statement "select select o.column1 + o.column2 from MyTestTable o where o.row[*] = mytesttabl0_.""row"" AND o.id = mytesttabl0_.id as col_0_0_ from MyTestTable mytesttabl0_ where mytesttabl0_.id=1 and mytesttabl0_.""row""=1 limit ?"; expected "identifier";

The problem here is that since row is a reserved keyword, the query ends up giving a syntax error (in o.row).
This is the point where you would think that adding quotes around it would be the solution.

```
@Formula("select o.column1 + o.column2" +
            " from MyTestTable o where `o.row` = `row` AND o.id = id")
    private int calculatedSum;
```

But this gives another error:

16:18:30.547 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column "mytesttabl0_.o.row" not found; SQL statement:
select select o.column1 + o.column2 from MyTestTable o where mytesttabl0_."o.row" = mytesttabl0_."row" AND o.id = mytesttabl0_.id as col_0_0_ from MyTestTable mytesttabl0_ where mytesttabl0_.id=1 and mytesttabl0_."row"=1 limit ? [42122-199]

The o.row has now been prefixed with an additional alias giving me mytesttabl0_.o.row
Which should just be o.row

How do i write a working reference to MyTestTable.row in this scenario?

Comment: What is your underlying SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: Unit tests are on H2, Production on MySQL. 
If we can get this passing on unit tests ill mark that as the answer.

Comment: Just as an aside, it's usually a bad idea to use two different database for testing and development.  So, you might want to just use MySQL everywhere.  I suspect that you're not really doing unit testing in some cases, but rather _integration_ testing, where you actually hit the H2 database running in memory.

Comment: Ideally this would be the way to go, but i have yet to figure out a way to run MySQL as an in-memory database for testing.
And it is true that we should call these integration tests, and not unit tests. I think these terms may have become a bit mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362921/hibernate-formula-query-field-using-another-formula-field) accepted answer, what appears inside `@Formula` has to be a valid *SQL* fragment, and it's not possible to refer to any fields inside your class; you may only refer to SQL columns and tables.  Assuming you just want Hibernate to populate the `calculatedSum` field with the sum of `column1` and `column2`, you should be using:

```
@Formula(" column1 + column2 ")
private int calculatedSum;
```

Comment: Well done sir!
Seems i overcomplicated things, matching on primary keys were unnescessary.

Comment: Yeah...so the thing is, the logic you were using seemed to just be ensuring that the sum uses the values from the current entity, but `@Formula` already handles this for you.

Comment: Ye, i thought those could only be referenced like that if they were already mapped up in the entity class through fields.