# Sorting does not work correctly! Java SORT

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am writing `MVC` `Rest` online store. I use `Spring Boot`, `Hibernate` and `PostgreSQL` in my project. I have drinks and want to be able to sort them when I receive them. By name and price, everything is good, but I can't sort by popularity. For this I use `Pagination` and `Sort`. In the drink class, I use the `ordersCount` variable, which I marked with the `@Formula` annotation and wrote a `sql`-query. The request itself must take a drink from the cart by `ID` and return its quantity. Separately, I checked the request in the database, and it works correctly. But when I make a `REST` request, I get those drinks that are not in the basket at all. What could be the problem?

ENUM for Sorting type:

```java
public enum SortingParams {

    PRICE_INCREASE, PRICE_DECREASE, NAME_INCREASE, POP_DECREASE
}
```

I write method for Sorting:

```java
     /*
     * @param sortingParams
     * @param page
     * @param pageSize
     * @return PageRequest
     */
    public PageRequest sortingWithParams(SortingParams sortingParams, int page, int pageSize) {

        switch (sortingParams) {

            case PRICE_INCREASE:
                return PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("price").ascending());

            case PRICE_DECREASE:
                return PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("price").descending());

            case NAME_INCREASE:
                return PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("name").ascending());

            case POP_DECREASE:
                return PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by("ordersCount").descending());

            default:
                return PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.unsorted());
        }
    }
```

Drink class:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "drink")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Drink {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private BigDecimal price;

    @Formula("(select sum(c.count) from cart_items c where c.drink_id = id)")
    private Long ordersCount;

    private String about;

    private int weight;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "packaging_id")
    private Packaging packaging;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;
```

This is how I then use this method:

```java
public PageDTO<CoffeeDTO> findAll(int page, int pageSize, SortingParams sortingParams) {

        final Page<Coffee> coffees = coffeeRepository
                .findAll(drinkService.sortingWithParams(sortingParams, page, pageSize));

        return new PageDTO<>(coffeeMapper.coffeeToCoffeesDTO(coffees));
    }
```

RESULT:
`http://localhost:8080/coffee/coffees?page=0&page_size=5&sortingParams=POP_DECREASE`

```
{
  "totalElements": 9,
  "totalPages": 2,
  "number": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Mokka",
      "price": 590,
      "about": "Mokka - это крепкий и ароматный кофе средней степени обжарки (3 по 5-тибальной шкале Paulig).",
      "weight": 800,
      "packaging": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Вакуумная упаковка"
      },
      "manufacturer": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Nescafe"
      },
      "country": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Франция"
      },
      "coffeeType": null,
      "roasting": null
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Бурбон",
      "price": 320,
      "about": "Бурбон - свое название сорт получил в честь географической родины – французского острова Бурбон (ныне Реюньон). Именно здесь в начале XVIII века прижились первые саженцы кофейных деревьев, вывезенных из Йемена.",
      "weight": 400,
      "packaging": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Жестяная банка"
      },
      "manufacturer": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Jacobs"
      },
      "country": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Страна тотемов"
      },
      "coffeeType": null,
      "roasting": null
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Жокей",
      "price": 1199,
      "about": "Жокей - насыщенный, крепкий, ароматный, с пряными нотками Жокей Для турки создан искусным сочетанием лучших сортов кофе из Центральной и Южной Америки, Африки и Индии. Особо мелкий помол идеален для приготовления кофе в турке.",
      "weight": 850,
      "packaging": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Стеклаянная банка"
      },
      "manufacturer": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Nescafe"
      },
      "country": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Индия"
      },
      "coffeeType": null,
      "roasting": null
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Oro",
      "price": 790,
      "about": "Ароматный напиток Oro, созданный для требовательного кофемана с утонченным вкусом. Тщательно подобранный купаж создан из 100 % высокогорной арабики, выращенной на лучших плантациях Центральной Америки. Средняя обжарка и высокое качество сырья позволяют получить ярко выраженный красочный вкус и запоминающийся аромат, наполненный выразительной цветочной нотой с небольшой горчинкой.",
      "weight": 750,
      "packaging": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Vacuum"
      },
      "manufacturer": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Jacobs"
      },
      "country": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "China"
      },
      "coffeeType": null,
      "roasting": null
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Prince",
      "price": 730,
      "about": "srfrfrftring",
      "weight": 0,
      "packaging": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Vacuum"
      },
      "manufacturer": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Jacobs"
      },
      "country": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "India"
      },
      "coffeeType": null,
      "roasting": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: your case statements do not include a break; clause. Have you tried adding them in after each clause?

Comment: So where is the SQL query that gets the sorting wrong? And how exactly does that SQL statement generate that JSON result?

Comment: The DRINK class has an ordersCount field annotated with @Formula. There is a sql query. And at the expense of json, I did not understand quest

Comment: `break` operator is Unreachable statement.

Comment: Please show us the complete SQL statement with the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: this is my sql quert without `order by`: `@Formula("(select sum(c.count) from cart_items c where c.drink_id = id)")`. And `order by` I dont use anywhere.

Comment: If you don't use an `order by` why do you expect the rows to be sorted?

Comment: because I write special method `sortingWithParams()`, where I use Sort.by(). Method is in question.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to use `id` field from class which will not work since @Formula accepts SQL not HQL. Here it's been explained more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362921/hibernate-formula-query-field-using-another-formula-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remake `@Formula` query and it works:

```java
@Formula("coalesce((select sum(c.count) from cart_items c" +
            " where c.drink_id = id), 0)")
```

I add `coalesce()` from PostgreSQL.